# gcloud console indicating job is running, while hadoop application manager says it is finished

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform

The job that I've submitted to spark cluster is not finishing. I see it is pending forever, however logs say that even spark jetty connector is shut down:

```
17/05/23 11:53:39 INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.ServerConnector: Stopped ServerConnector@4f67e3df{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:4041}
```

I run latest cloud dataproc v1.1 (spark 2.0.2) on yarn. I submit spark job via gcloud api:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --project stage --cluster datasys-stg \
--async --jar hdfs:///apps/jdbc-job/jdbc-job.jar --labels name=jdbc-job -- --dbType=test
```

The same spark pi stuff is finished correctly:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --project stage --cluster datasys-stg --async \
 --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --jars file:///usr/lib/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples.jar -- 100
```

While visiting hadoop application manager interface I see it is finished with Successful result:
[image: hadoop application manager on port 8088 reports all is ok]
Google cloud console and job list is showing it is still running until killed (see job run for 20 hours before killed, while hadoop says it ran for 19 seconds):
[image: gcloud console shows it is running]
Is there something I can monitor to see what is preventing gcloud to finish the job?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything that I can monitor my application is not finishing, but I've found the actual problem and fixed it. Turns out I had abandoned threads in my application - I had connection to RabbitMQ and that seemed to create some threads that prevented application from being finally stoped by gcloud.